# Javascript request local server not a ec2 server

Tags: javascript, python, apache, networking, amazon-ec2

In ec2 instance, i build a apache server(80) and flask server (5000)

i hoped that if request to apache server index.html in local host, associated js file request to ec2 flask server(127.0.0.1:5000) to get json data

[image: hoped]

but in real, js file request to local 5000 port not a ec2 flask server

[image: real]

is any way to request ec2 flask server except open 5000 port at ec2 server??

Answer (score 0):

Your JS is making a request to `127.0.0.1:5000` which is `localhost` on your system. If you want to make JS make a request to the EC2, make sure that its sending the request to the IP of the EC2 instance, and not `127.0.0.1`

Comment: I want put flask server in private network ec2 at last, if use ec2 ip, i think local can't access private network. is it possible?

Comment: You should open up the Flask server's IP and then try it. You could also set up an Nginx reverse proxy to it.